# Creating a global array of Audioplayers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How does one create a global array of audioplayers so that I can call the players from other classes.

The Java equivalent to static?

I want to play multiple sounds. Is a different player needed for each, or can one player, just play random sounds throughout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array(NSMutableArray) in the AppDelegate class and you can add different players objects to that array, and you can access that array from any class

in App Delegate file, 
in .h file

```
NSMutableArray *playersArray;

@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *playersArray;
```

in .m file initialize that array

```
playersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in some other file you can access that array as follows

```
 AppDelegateClassName *appDelegate = (AppDelegateClassName *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate.playersArray addObject:onePlayerObject];
```

similarly you can access that player object by reading from that array.

Regards,

Satya.

Comment: How is the array created? Should it be set to global(what syntax) or is it just global automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need an array of players. one player is enough

Declare this in your appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
   player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];
}

-(void)playAudio:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString* file=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",fileName];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:file];
    NSLog(@"Path : %@",resourcePath);
    NSError* err;
    //Declare the player in your didFinishLaunching Dont declare here
    player.delegate = self;
    [player play];
}
```

Now wherever you want to play any file create a object to appDelegate

```
yourAppDelegate  *yourAppDelegateObject= (yourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Use that object to call that function

```
 [yourAppDelegateObject playAudio:filenameOftheAudioFile];
```